# How can I further reduce the loss value in a CNN model?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build a CNN to classify fruits. I've been experiencing high loss values and I'm trying to reduce it as much as I can but I'm not sure how to improve my model further.

Here is my code:

```
model96 = tf.keras.Sequential()

#Architecture
model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32,
                                 kernel_size = (3, 3),
                                 activation = "relu",
                                 input_shape = (96, 96, 3)))

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32,
                                 kernel_size = (3, 3),
                                 activation = "relu"))

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.25))

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=128, activation='relu'))

model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.5))

#output layer
model96.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=4, activation='softmax'))

#Loss function
model96.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

#Train model
hist96 = model96.fit(x=x_train96_norm, y=y_train, epochs=100)

#Test and Evaluate
print("Performance with test data:")
loss96, accuracy96 = model96.evaluate(x=x_test96_norm, y=y_test)
print('loss =', loss96)
print('accuracy =', accuracy96)
```

During training, the final loss value was 0.0153 and the final accuracy value was 0.9958, however, during the test the model scored: `loss = 1.0462701320648193` and  `accuracy = 0.8666666746139526`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info

Answer (score 2):

Your problem looks like a classical overfitting problem. You can add [EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping) to avoid this. EarlyStopping will stop the training process as soon as the validation loss stops decreasing. The code is pretty straightforward:

```
callback = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=3)

hist96 = model96.fit(x=x_train96_norm, y=y_train, epochs=100, callbacks=[callback])
```